# execute SQL commands (SQL Server) from a playbook using the Shell module

Tags: sql, sql-server, shell, ansible

This is my first experience in ansible. I would like to create a yaml playbook in order to execute commands on an SQL server (Linux) and using the Shell module.
I did not find tutorials or examples on the internet. Could you please help me (with hints or links to tutorials)?

thank you

Comment: There are plenty of examples for "How to execute SQL commands via `shell` module in Ansible?" here on Stackoverflow, i.e. like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69677323/6771046). Nevertheless it is recommend to use the appropriate modules for MySQL or PostgreSQL to execute queries.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a good place to start:

[Execute shell commands on targets](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html)

Learning shell scripting is a large topic I recommend the book:
Steve Parker, (2011) Shell Scripting: Expert Recipes for Linux, Bash and more. ISBN-13:978-1118024485